# Error Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type SimpleImageUpload

Tags: vb.net, image

I'm having problem with converting string to type SimpleImageUpload of piczard it's a control that you can upload a picture.if anyone run into that problem before I would love to get some help....

In my code I'm grabbing the ImageUploaderPerson1.ID.ToString() and I'm trying assigned it to type SimpleImageUpload in order to manipulate that later.

Here is my code:

```
Dim Pictures As New Hashtable
Dim pic As DictionaryEntry
Dim retValPic As SimpleImageUpload = New SimpleImageUpload()
Dim button As String = hfPictureIndex.Value
PictureInfo.PictureIndex = Convert.ToInt16(button)
Pictures.Add("1", ImageUploaderPerson1.ID.ToString())
Pictures.Add("2", ImageUploaderPerson2.ID.ToString())

For Each pic In Pictures
    If pic.Key.ToString() = button.ToString() Then

        retValPic = pic.Value '*trying to convert it here!

        '** Saving Picture
        If retValPic.HasImage Then
        End If
Next
```

Comment: Why do you think that you should be able to convert a string to an image uploader?

Comment: I'm trying I don't know if I can able to do this that's why I'm asking here....I need the ID of the control in order to manipulate that later.

Comment: Not sure why do you expect assigning string (as result of `ToString()` call) to `type SimpleImageUpload` to produce anything but error you see. Please clarify.

Comment: there is any other way to get the ID of the control instead something like this {ASP.controls_simpleimageuploadusercontrol_simpleimageupload_ascx} without the ID.ToString() at the end

Answer (score 0):

Try a Dictionary with a reference to the actual object instead of a hashtable.

```
Dim Pictures As New Dictionary(Of String, SimpleImageUpload)
Dim retValPic As SimpleImageUpload = New SimpleImageUpload()
Dim button As String = hfPictureIndex.Value
PictureInfo.PictureIndex = Convert.ToInt16(button)
Pictures.Add("1", ImageUploaderPerson1)
Pictures.Add("2", ImageUploaderPerson2)

For Each pic as KeyValuePair(Of String, SimpleImageUpload) In Pictures
    If pic.Key.ToString() = button.ToString() Then

        retValPic = pic.Value '*trying to convert it here!

        '** Saving Picture
        If retValPic.HasImage Then
        End If
Next
```